# Why is only derived class member function called?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, overloading, method-hiding

In the following code:
Please tell me why only derived class member function is called, is it because of `hiding`? And why an error doesn't occur in `b.func(1.1);`, the parameter is `int x`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual int func(float x)
    {
        cout << "A";
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual int func(int x)
    {
        cout << "B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.func(1);   // B
    b.func(1.1); // B

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's because of *hiding*. This is one of the main reasons you should always add the special identifier `override` on functions you intend to override:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual int func(int x) override  // <- Note the override here
    {
        cout << "B";
    }
};
```

This will cause the compiler to complain about not actually overriding.

And [floating point values can be implicitly converted to integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions).